# Tomcat 7 redirect to https vs web.xml

Tags: tomcat, servlets, https

I've found the following snippet to add to my web.xml to force requests to redirect to https:

```
<security-constraint>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <user-data-constraint>
            <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
        </user-data-constraint>
    </security-constraint>
```

That seems like it should do the job, and my app is redirecting requests to https just fine.

However, online recommendations suggest doing this as well in the server.xml:

```
<Connector port="8080" enableLookups="false" redirectPort="8443" />
```

Why do I need to edit the server.xml? My app works without it, however, do I have a security hole that's left open? Will this cause unforeseen problems in the future?

Answer (score 0):

The default value for `redirectPort` is `8443` so that's why you are observing no change when you add that. If you wanted to instead redirect to port `443`, you'd have to set the `redirectPort` appropriately or your users would be redirected to `host:8443`.

Using `CONFIDENTIAL` causes Tomcat to redirect and switch protocols, and the `redirectPort` specifies the port number that will be used in the URL. You actually have to specify both (`CONFIDENTIAL` in `web.xml` *and* `redirectPort` in `server.xml`), though the `redirectPort` often already does what you want (as you've seen).